# Github actions for Rust shows Node.js warning (12 - 16)

Tags: rust, github-actions

Does anyone know why Node.js is needed here?

```yaml
name: Rust

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "develop" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "develop" ]

env:
  CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always

jobs:
  fmt:
    name: Rustfmt
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
        with:
          toolchain: stable
          override: true
          components: rustfmt
      - uses: actions-rs/cargo@v1
        with:
          command: fmt
          args: --all -- --check
...
```

> Rustfmt
>
> Node.js 12 actions are deprecated.
> For more information see:
> https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/.
>
> Please update the following actions to use Node.js 16: actions-rs/toolchain, actions-rs/cargo

[Full source](https://github.com/Trenrod/book_zerotoproduction/blob/develop/.github/workflows/rust.yml)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The GitHub actions mentioned in that quote are themselves dependent on Node.js, specifically on major version 12 of Node.js.
And, as stated in that quote, [the use of Node.js 12 in actions has recently become deprecated](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/).

Support for Node.js 12 will not be dropped out of a sudden. However, maintainers should act to update their actions and users should be on the look-out for new versions. Unfortunately in this case, issues have been filed for both actions here ([actions-rs/toolchain#219](https://github.com/actions-rs/toolchain/issues/219) and [actions-rs/cargo#216](https://github.com/actions-rs/cargo/issues/216)), but they might never be attended because [actions-rs is unmaintained since 2020](https://github.com/actions-rs/toolchain/issues/216). As such, we may need to rely on **alternative actions**.

To use [`setup-rust-toolchain`](https://github.com/actions-rust-lang/setup-rust-toolchain), for example, we can port the `fmt` job to in the question into the code below.

```yaml
  # Check formatting with rustfmt
  fmt:
    name: Rustfmt
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions-rust-lang/setup-rust-toolchain@v1
        with:
          toolchain: stable
          components: rustfmt
      - name: Check formatting
        uses: actions-rust-lang/rustfmt@v1
```

---

Alternatively, there is [dtolnay's toolchain action](https://github.com/dtolnay/rust-toolchain).

```yaml
  fmt:
    name: Rustfmt
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: dtolnay/rust-toolchain@stable
        with:
          components: rustfmt
      - name: Check formatting
        run: cargo fmt --all -- --check
```